# Setting destination MQMD properties without the com.ibm libraries

Tags: java, jms, ibm-mq

I have to use JMS in order to send messages with IBM MQ queues. The libraries used are

> javax.jms.*

Everything works as expected. Unfortunately the queue itself needs advanced properties set on the MQMD (message descriptor). To do so you would have to enable them first on a destination with

```
((JmsDestination) destination).setBooleanProperty(WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED, true);
```

which uses the

> import com.ibm.msg.client.jms.JmsDestination;

library. Due to technical reasons I am not allowed to use these libraries. Is there a way to get this working with the standard javax libraries?

The only MQMD fields I need to define manually is the replyToQueueManager and the UserId

Edit: I can get it working with reflections but still some fields are not set as expected

Comment: What you want to do is not core JMS and is a IBM MQ JMS extension.  I do not know of anyway you could access this with out using the IBM classes.

Comment: I figured out how to achieve this via reflections but the attribute I need to set (replyToQueueManager) is nonetheless not set. Maybe because of read only restrictions..

Comment: It is documented that you must set `WMQConstants.WMQ_MQMD_WRITE_ENABLED` to `true` in order to write directly to the MQMD.  I wonder why you are not setting the equivalent JMS reply to property which should automatically populate the MQMD `replyToQueueManager`.  Something like `queue://replyToQueueManager_value/replyToQueue_value` should populate the MQMD fields.

Comment: If those are the only MQMD fields you need to populate and it works then please update the question and I'll post it as a answer.

Comment: replyToQueueManager  and UserId would be the relevant fields